# Count.cgi remote code execute how is it possible?

Tags: web-application

Recently scanning my website using nikto and it tells me that on /cgi-sys/Count.cgi allows remote attackers to execute arbitrary commands, anyone have any idea how it works? some help would be great.

Comment: Can you give us the Count.cgi source and your version bash?

Comment: Nikko should give a reference number you can google for more information. It could also be a false positive as not all of the nikto database entries are reliable. @Florian may be correct in assuming it is a shellshock vulnerability which is pretty easy to check for with some googling. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to say for sure what is really going on with this few information, i.e. having only a generic script name and no detailed messages about the kind of error found. But  `count.cgi` is included in the [nikto source code](https://github.com/sullo/nikto/blob/master/program/databases/db_variables) in the following line:

```
@SHELLSHOCK= admin.cgi ... count.cgi  ...
```

This suggest that nikto might have found your system vulnerable to [Shellshock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_(software_bug)) and that this can be exploited through `count.cgi`. For more information see the many many [questions about the shellshock vulnerability on this site](https://security.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=shellshock%20is%3aquestion).